# Is it possible to configure Python interpreter to provide more useful info on errors?

Tags: python, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

For example, can "IndexError: list index out of range" actually say what value in which variable caused the error and what the bound was? Eg. rather than bare

```
a[i][j] += max(a[i][j-d], a[i-1][j])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Get this:

```
IndexError: list index out of range: j-d=250 for expected range of [0:250]
```

This could cut quite some time of the most mundane development process that otherwise I waste on backtracking the code or inserting print statements to obtain such info.

Comment: the location where the exception is raised probably cannot know which expression caused the error (`j-d` has already been evaluated). You also forgot to ask for "which object triggers this error".... nice idea, but you should look into list comprehension and iterate on the values instead of indices to avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: No, Python cannot be configured to do this.  I suppose a fancy IDE could do it, but the extra information wouldn't be coming from Python at all.

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes of course. According to Python Doc (from python IDLE > Help Menu> Python 
 Docs> Q&A Section), in question "Is There a source code level debugger with breakponts, single-stepping, ect..?" they mentioned some of the tools helping you debug your code, they are "PythonWin ","Boa Constructor","Eric","Pydb", and other commercial IDE such as "Wing IDE", "Komodo IDE", and "PyCharm". They are worth to try. Thanks

Comment: you can wrap offending code in a try/except. **pdb.set_trace()** in the except will get you the debugger. **pp locals()** will pretty print variables and len(your_list) should giv some insight.  from traceback import print_exc can also help , but you need to p-prefix it as **p print_exc()** when in debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the library [`better_exceptions`](https://github.com/Qix-/better-exceptions).

```
import better_exceptions

a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
i, j, d = 1, 350, 100
a[i][j] += max(a[i][j-d], a[i-1][j])
```

[image: better_exceptions output]

This is not exactly what you are asking for (`better_exceptions` simply displays all variable values, errors messages are not more explicit), but I think it is a good start.